# Summarizing by group and subgroup and show data conditionally

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I want to group report by Data field Companyname and Subgroup data by AccountType . I want to Calculate Sale for report column Previous Year sale where SaleDate is 30/12/2019 from Transaction table. Another calculation for report column This Month sale where SaleDate between 01/01/2020 to 31/01/2020 from  Transaction table. And Finally Calculate Total  for report column Total Previous Year Sale + This Month Sale.
My Table Sales is here:

```html
+----------+--------------+-------------+------+
| SaleDate | Company Name | AccountType | Sale |
+----------+--------------+-------------+------+
| 30/12/19 | ABC          | I           | 500  |
| 30/12/19 | CBA          | K           | 3000 |
| 01/01/20 | ABC          | I           | 600  |
| 10/01/20 | ABC          | J           | 1000 |
| 11/01/20 | CBA          | O           | 2000 |
| 21/01/20 | ABC          | L           | 3000 |
| 22/01/20 | CBA          | O           | 2500 |
| 23/01/20 | CBA          | K           | 3400 |
+----------+--------------+-------------+------+
```

Output I want from the above table is

```html
+--------------+-------------+---------------+-------+
Company Name: ABC                                    |
+-------------+---------------+------------+---------+
| AccountType | Previous Year | This Month |  Total  |
+-------------+---------------+------------+---------+
| I           |      500      |     600    |  1100   |
| J           |      000      |    1000    |  1000   |
| L           |      000      |    3000    |  3000   |
+-------------+---------------+------------+---------+
Sub-Total:    |      500      |    4600    |  4100   |      
+-------------+---------------+------------+---------+
Company Name: CBA                                    |
+--------------+--------------+------------+---------+
| K           |     3000      |    3400    |  6400   |
| O           |      000      |    4500    |  4500   |
+-------------+---------------+------------+---------|
Sub-Total:    |     3000      |    7900    | 10900   |      
+-------------+---------------+------------+---------+
GrandTotal:   |     3500      |   12500    | 15000   |      
+-------------+---------------+------------+---------+
```

How can i create this type of report.

Comment: you can use SSRS or Crystal reports. for  SSRS check this link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-create-report-using-report-viewer-in-asp-net1                        for Cystal report check this link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/create-crystal-report-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: I have not found solution there.

Comment: please explain what do you tried?

Comment: There is no instructions how to create report like my report. There is instructions to create simple report only. But my report is too complicated.